Adjust UIImage Color
I'd like to modify the color of Images in SwiftUI. Currently, I'm trying to modify the .foregroundColor() as such, but it's not actually modifying it whatsoever from black
Image(uiImage: resizeImage(UIImage(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 75, height: 27))!)
    .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .yellow : .gray)

As you can see, the color is still black:

Ideally, I'd want to modify it to have this .foregroundColor, that is the color of its outline, and when the like button (heart) is pressed, it fills with that same color:
foregroundColor(colorPalettes[safe: sharedVars.colorPaletteIndex]?[2] ?? .white)
This is currently the color being applied to the like count next to the like button (heart image):


Why not just Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart") directly?

If I remember correctly, foregroundColor will be deprecated soon, so need to use foregroundStyle instead.

@aheze I recall adding the resizeImage() with the targetSize, instead of just directly doing that, because it's what allows for me to size those three images the same.

Why is there a UIImage here in the first place, just use resizable and frame

Will that help me solve my coloring issue @loremipsum?

Maybe you usually multiply images but I know the rendering modes can be changed to show color too. I dont remember off the top of my head how to do it.

@Daggerpov uhhh yeah that's kind of weird with system icons. You can make them all the same size with .font(.title) or something. And to make further adjustments you can just do .scaleEffect

While debugging, it is a good idea to leave out additional code like your custom func resizeImage(..) as much as possible.

Credit to @aheze and @LawrenceGimenez for their comments under my question suggesting these changes:
Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
    .font(.title)
    .scaleEffect(1)
    .foregroundStyle(colorPalettes[safe: sharedVars.colorPaletteIndex]?[2] ?? .white)

Using the base Image object and adjusting its .foregroundStyle works as intended in my question for getting the color to match my variable:



To note for anyone seeing this, I did have to surround this code with an iOS version check to accommodate the .foregroundStyle() method call: if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {I put the above code in these curly brackets}

Btw even though foregroundColor is deprecated it should be still fine to use.

SwiftUI's Image already has the Image(systemName:) initializer, so there is no need to take a UIImage detour.
The following code does what you need in pure SwiftUI, without UIKit, custom functions or force unwrapping:
struct LikeView: View {
    @State private var isLiked = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 75, height: 27)
            .foregroundStyle(isLiked ? .yellow : .white)
        
            .onTapGesture {
                isLiked.toggle()
            }
    }
}

Note: onTapGesture was added for easy reproducability.
As proposed in the comments, you could also skip the hard-coded resizing and have the image adapt to any parent view's font sizing:
someView {
    Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
        .foregroundStyle(isLiked ? .yellow : .primary)
}
.font(.title)

